# out of memory when concatenate Audio Files with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to concatenate 70 audio files

this is the command ... when XXXX the number if the audio files. 
Each audio file has delay.

When i trying to do it with about 30 audio files ( or less then 30 ) - it work good

But with 70 ( or more ) its crash with out of memory

How to solve it ?

"-i", "/storage/input1.wav", "-i", "/storage/input2.wav" ..... , "-filter_complex", "[1]adelay=8000|8000[s1];[1]adelay=125000|125000[s2] .... ;[0][s1][s2] .... amix=XXXX[mixout]" -map "[mixout]"  "/storage/output.wav"

Comment: Do it in multiple instances: `[0][s1]...[s29]amix=30[a];[s30][s31]...[s59]amix=30[b];[s60][s61]...[s69]amix=10[c];[a][b][c]amix=3"`

Comment: no .. .this is not the reason

Comment: What is not the reason?